# How to know if someone is using Yesware?

Tags: webapp-rec

I [previously asked](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44547/13351) if it might be possible to prevent people from using Yesware against you. The answer: **Yes. Disable images** -- especially for people you do not know. I'm not all that satisfied with this answer, as images seem to be an important aspect of the email experience (and even my trusted friends might be using Yesware to keep tabs on me).

Is there a way, perhaps via a Gmail extension or other application that can be used to track the trackers, to know if the Yesware pixel was served?

(Kind of like how Snapchat lets you know when someone has screengrabbed one of your snaps.)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a link in a formatted email that creates a get request, you can track this through the use of some kind of proxy and browsing the logs (or blocking it through the proxy then reading the logs for requests blocked).

Or you can use a tool that analyzes the raw text of emails for embedded URLS.

I don't know of any extensions or plugins for tracking this offhand, but it doesn't mean they don't exist.